# MSSQL Joining 3 Tables with more than 1 row to a single line result over multiple records

Tags: php, sql-server, database

Ok, I'll try to explain this as best I can here.

I have multiple tables that are to be connected through a JOIN where certain reference points meet.

In one of the tables, there are 2 or more results over several rows that I need to bring back to separate columns.

In the diagram below (I hope that explains it better), T2.ColA is connected to T3.ColA and T1,ColA is connected to T2.ColB.

In ColC of T1, there is a latest record. These are the only ones that are required to results. Note that ColC could be different dates between rows 1 and 2 for example. But it needs the latest for each ColB based on ColA.

But in T1, there are two rows which need Col B to return to the result in separate columns.

[image: DB Example]

By the way, this is just one entry - there will be thousands of rows that need to return a result - not just 1.

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: And what should happen if there are 3 rows in table1, with values, say `1123`, `3211` and `3333`? Which two should be chosen? Or you want three columns in that case? And what if there is only 1 row in `table1`?

Comment: There actually is. So the query would need to specify only to look for the latest of 1123 and 3211. There may be 1 entry for 123, but it will contain rows for both 1123 and 3211 as well as others such as 3333 and 4444 etc that will be referenced via 123

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select t1.cola,t2.cola,t1.colb,t2.colb,t3.colb FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.cola = t2.colb INNER JOIN table3 ON t3.cola =t2.cola
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this could solve your query..

```
SELECT T1.COLA, T1.COLB, T2.COLA, T2.COLA
FROM 
TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3
WHERE
T1.COLC = (
SELECT MAX(T4.COLC) FROM TABLE1 T4 WHERE T4.COLA = T1.COLA
)
```

** But as you have specified in your dig, it's not possible to display 1123, 3211 in a single row. It has to be in two different rows, coz its changes dynamically depending on the row count. You can modify as you want using your front end application.

Comment: he could use a sub query and a concat to return it as a comma separated string from the multi select table, then he'll just have to do a little php to sort it out after

Comment: Yes, he can achieve that by using a delimiter. But a saperate column for each entry, I dont think so.

Comment: ofc he can `SELECT t1.stuff, t3.stuff, (select concat(",",column) FROM tbl2 where tbl2.ID=tbl1.subid) as T2string JOINs....inners..stuff.`